# Order of technician calculation with accumulative power moves?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

Basically, my question is probably about order of calculations.
Technician works for moves that have power of 60 or lower while accumulative power moves get stronger each time they are used (eg Fury Cutter). Which calculation happens first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the Fury Cutter Power is calculated by the amount of times it is used (40 * times used iirc). When it is below 60 Power, Technician is applied. So only the first turn it works. ([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67924272))

This holds for all moves. First the power is calculated by the rules of the move. The. Technician is applied if it's applicable.